# Generic query for MySQL and PGSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to create a generic query which work with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

For this query, I need to select all column in 3 tables but the result need to have a distinct clause on the ID to eliminate duplicates rows.
Actually in the database, there is 6 records but just 3 are differents:
One of them appears 3 times, an other appears 2 and the last just on.
Records which appears many time are exactly the same and I just want keep one of each.

This is a picture of the 6 records:
[image: 6 records]

And me I want that:
[image: Just distinct record]

Here is the MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_1
  INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
  INNER JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.table_3_id = table_3.id
WHERE
  table_3.type = 'foo'
GROUP BY
  table_1.id
```

And this is the PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (table_1.id)
  *
FROM
  table_1
  INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1.id
  INNER JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.table_3_id = table_3.id
WHERE
  table_3.type = 'foo'
```

I don't find how to create just one query which work with MySQL and PostgreSQL

Comment: Why *? Which values do you need when there are more than one matching records available in table_2 for a value in table_1? Use ANSI `GROUP BY` and ANSI rules for `GROUP BY`: Aggregate or list in `GROUP BY` for each columns listed in `SELECT`. **What is your REAL problem, you are trying to solve?**

Comment: Brut-force solution: `select * from (select table_1.*, (select id from table_2 where table_1.id = table_2.table_1.id order by <order> limit 1) as t2_id, ... from table_1) t inner join table_2 on (t.t2_id = table_2.id) ...` However do not try to write the "generic" solution because you are lost the most of advantages of the each DBMS. Create stored functions instead and code each in the most DBMS-related efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first get the distinct ids of the first table, then join the rest on to them.

Though, you will still get somewhat random values for table_1 I guess, if there are multiples ids with different values to them and you not specifying which you want.

```
SELECT
    table_1.*, table_2.*, table_3.* 
FROM
    (SELECT table_1.id FROM table_1 GROUP BY table_1.id) AS distinctIds
INNER JOIN table_1 ON table_1.id = distinctIds.id 
INNER JOIN table_2 ON distinctIds.id = table_2.table_1_id
INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_2.table_3_id = table_3.id
WHERE
    table_3.type = "foo"
```

Comment: It seems you forgot the "SELECT" after the first FROM, but I tried it with PgSQL and MySQL I have the good result but with duplicates row

Comment: See comment under question. Rephrased: What duplicate means and what are the rules to remove them. Is the table1.id appears twice, or whole records are appearing twice or more? Which records are the ones you want to get when a duplicate appears? It is hard to help with a such abstract question.

Comment: duplicates appear, when one or multiple of the joins is a 1:n join (or m:n), distincts may not help and I wonder why this construct in psql is supported.

Comment: Okay, it's the whole records which are appearing tiwce (or more). There is 6 records but 3 differents:
One of them appears 3 times, a other appears 2 and the last just one, and me I just want to keep one each

Comment: Can you add that information to your question and also add, by which criteria you want to decide which values to keep?